# can we customize hash code in react build file

Tags: reactjs, build, create-react-app, bundle, production

When we create our build with react script, (CRA boilerplate), we get some hash value in bundle.js file, can we customize it according to some uniqeTImestamp value,

we can do this while we configuring in webpack.config.js but how we do that while project is configured with create-react-app

currently  : [image]

wanted to  :
[image]